# Authentication token type [(null)] is not supported

Tags: linux, ldap, sssd

I have configured sssd on my servers (some RHEL and CentOS 6), but on some of them, I get the following error in `/var/log/sssd/sssd_example.com.log`:

```
[sssd[be[example.com]]] [sdap_auth_send] (1): Authentication token type [(null)] is not supported
[sssd[be[example.com]]] [fo_set_port_status] (4): Marking port 389 of server 'example.com' as 'not working'
```

SSSD is configured to use an LDAP server. `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` contains:

```
[..]
ldap_default_bind_dn = CN=example,cn=com 
ldap_default_authtok_type = obfuscated_password 
ldap_default_authtok = AAAgAE/vW3+JSwU737kaW/fByo/8zxXgFqyrsFn62RiOyuo2C9475/X9Ps5jnNvm6T61mQW3gjPrzr8tqWIbRh7qrGTe/TDiHkt13l4r8yMqCqpeAAECAyEC
[..]
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to `ldap_default_authtok_type` which has an invalid value.

In my case, I prepared my setup on some RHEL/CentOS 6.2 servers, but deployed it on some old RHEL/CentOS 6.0 servers, which don't support `obfuscated_password` scheme (see [sss_obfuscate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sss_obfuscate)).

So there are two options:

- Upgrade your system, so `obfuscated_password` is supported by sssd.
- Use non obfuscated password in sssd.conf:

Example:

```
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = mycleartextpassword
```